# mkdir -p src/main/java src/main/resources Syntax Error?

Tags: java

I'm trying to follow this(https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/java) guide; however, I'm having trouble with Step #2. I can't quite figure out why I'm getting the error message "The syntax of the command is incorrect" when I copy-paste mkdir -p src/main/java src/main/resources into cmd.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You seem running Linux command on Windows.

The equivalent command of `mkdir -p src/main/java src/main/resources` on Windows Command Prompt is `mkdir src\main\java src\main\resources`. No `-p` needed, and note the direction of slashes.